# Error: Cannot find module './img.jpg' on react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a functional component of react, I was trying to use the URL of the image coming from props with the code  `<img src={require(productUrl).default}/>`(here the productUrl is coming from props) but there was an error that the module was not found I also did a console log for productUrl  it printed the expected value and when I hardcoded the value of the url inside the require It was working but I cannot use the hardcoded value as the URL is coming from props

Comment: Hello @vanshika: I hope url of the image is coming as `productUrl.default` prop. Right? 
Then try the answer that I have provided. Hope this will be helpful :)

Comment: Yes it was right as I did a console log of the productUrl and I hardcodded the same in the URL which was working fine

Comment: OK, OK. So You mean `productUrl` contains the correct img source, in that case we  only need to use `<img src={productUrl} alt="my image"/>`

Comment: @vanshila: Better if you share your code with us: Or try going through this article, Hope this helps https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-display-images-in-react-dfe22a66d5e7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `require` within React Component.
Try to directly use your **prop** in the **img** `src`. Something like this:

```
<img src={productUrl} alt="my image"/>
```

Considering `productUrl` contains the correct `url` source for the image :)

Since, you have not added any code in the question. Hope this article would be useful as per your requirement from **BetterProgramming.pub**
[betterprogramming.pub/how-to-display-images-in-react](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-display-images-in-react-dfe22a66d5e7)

**UPDATE: After getting idea from Comment Sections**
After getting the codebase, I have fixed the issues with this.

**CodeSandBox Link:** https://codesandbox.io/s/issuewithimage-qmkpg

Some of the major issue were:

1. products array were wrongly exported as a function while we could directly export them and we do not need any function.
2. Since you are using local images in this case we must make sure we place them in the public folder and do not use relative path (which leads to issues).So place all the images that you wish to use in public folder as I have done and use same names in your products array.
3. Rest you may figure out from the code. :D

CHEERS !!!

Comment: I did that as well but it did not work because I think in react we can use URL of the image only if it is imported

Comment: No, We can directly also use it, if we have correct URL coming  in the prop. I use it everyday.
Could you just show me the console of the prop object your component is receiving :) ?

Comment: We only need to cross check, whether `productUrl.default` is a correct URL for the image

Comment: product.jsx:12 ./img2.jpg
product.jsx:12 ./img3.jpg
product.jsx:12 ./img1.jpg this was the console of the productUrl that I received

Comment: Hmmm. Well, this clearly is not what we expect for a img source. Since we do not know the exact code.

So dear friend. Do one thing, either create a *codesandbox* project for the same and  share the link with me so that I can have a look and resolve this InshaAllah.  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new 

Or we can see what to do, May be connect later briefly for the same. But I believe `codesandbox `project would be more than enough for me to fix this :) 

Fingers crossed.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/1897d91b1c9   The Url for the code

Comment: @vanshika Sure, Let me have a look InshaAllah :) Fingers Crossed

Comment: Dear @vanshika The above codesandbox link is not working. 
Please go through this small 3-4 minute video to see how to do it. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwxkGm6hxqw 

At 1:33 of the video you can see a url is generated, The same way once you add all your code, save it (Ctrl+S) on windows and then share the samw link with me. So that I can see where the problem is.

And if you feeling difficulty in this, Just push your code to github and share the repository link with me. I will pull the code and clone and work it out InshaAllah :)

Comment: I am sorry my bad I have regenerated the  link again hope this time it works https://codesandbox.io/s/components-7izew

Comment: @vanshika: Ya, I saw this and fixed it. I have made necessary changes for you. 
Have a great day !!!

Comment: @vanshika: Please check my updated answer. Hope this helps. And Praise is to God only who helped me to resolve it for you :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I was able to help. I hope every developer keeps this culture to help one another alive which unfortunately I see less in work cultures at least for the time I have worked so far and am working.

God Bless, Let Humanity prevail.